# Frames in erb Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, frames, erb

I need the information to create frames in erb rails.

I need to display the links in a frames instead of provide as link to new window.

Eg.

```
a href="taxas?[gm]=<%= prefer.genus_name %>&[sp]=<%= prefer.sp_epithet%>" target="new">Link /a
```

This should be modified as

```
frame href="taxas?[gm]=<%= prefer.genus_name %>&[sp]=<%= prefer.sp_epithet%>"> /frame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so in ERB, you can always put in

```
<frameset cols="25%,75%">
   <frame src="frame_a.htm" />
   <frame src="<%=  url_as_ruby_string  %>" />
</frameset>
```

or you can use `<iframe>` too.

Comment: The source is not the another html file, its the same file and params will vary. Your reply will help, if source will be another file. Kindly give me suggestion to open same source file with different params.

Comment: <iframe> works great for same source file with different params. But not <frame>. I used <iframe>, Thanks for your valuable comment.